# how to make scalatest generate html report through sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest, specs2

The way to do this for specs2 based test in sbt is

```
(testOptions in Test) += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.Specs2, "html")
```

but how about scalatest? I've done lots of Google search, but cannot find a good explanation/solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

so two things I need to do...

I. use any scalatest artifact after 2.0.M5b. For me, I added this dependency,

`org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.0.M6" % "test->*" excludeAll (
  ExclusionRule(organization="org.junit", name="junit")
)`

"test->*" is necessary, otherwise dependencies needed to generate the html wont be downloaded. (There must be a better way than this)

II. In build.sbt, add

`(testOptions in Test) += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-u", "target/report")`

Comment: This should be -h for html reporting.  -u is xml reporting.

Comment: This does not work with Scalatest 3.0.7: `Symbol 'type org.scalactic.TripleEquals' is missing from the classpath.`  It also complains about `Tolerance` and `term org.scalactic.source`. Any idea how to update this for 3.0?

Answer (score 5):

beware with that setting.

org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.0.M6" % "test->*

It pulls out some junit:junit:3.8.1 dependency which ivy fails to resolve. see [this bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IVY-1326)

this is a better way to do it in ScalaTest 2.0

```
testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-u", "target/test-reports")
```

This works well in Jenkins

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it.
Change your `build.sbt` in this way:

```
Test/testOptions := Seq(
  Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-h", "target/scalatest")
),
projectDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.9" //% Test,
  "com.vladsch.flexmark" % "flexmark" % "0.36.8" % Test,
  "com.vladsch.flexmark" % "flexmark-profile-pegdown" % "0.36.8" % Test,
  ...
)
```

The `flexmark` dependency isn't documented but it is necessary.
An HTML report will be generated in the `target/scalatest` directory.
You can publish it with Jenkins.
I've tested with more recent versions of flexmark, but it doesn't work.